# Excel VBA 2013 - How to disable Event Click on Listbox when 11th column reached.

Tags: excel, listbox, event-handling, vba

I'm using ListBox on UserForm to list Lines of Order my application XLSM.
I understood that there is a limit of column number for a ListBox when AddItem VBA statement used but it can be worked around by using Array. And it works fine.

The problem is when I try to update LisBox with a value for precisely the 11th column, it triggers again the ListBox click event. For the others columns, before and after, there is no firing of that event.

Is that observation exact ? If true, how to disable this firing of ListBox Click because it creates a kind of unrequired side effects.

Thanks for your tips.

Regards.

Comment: What about disable the Listbox? `Listbox.Enabled = False`

Comment: No. I need the Click event to dispatch the column values in different textboxes...